# How do I parse Json file from azure blob storage to Azure Sql using Azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

[][1]I have a multiple json files dropping in blob storage weekly, I want to use azure logic app to parse json file and copy data into Azure Sql? Please help

Comment: what have you read about so far? what have you attempted so far? Pl see SO guidelines on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For achieving your requirement, Below are the flow that you can follow :-

Blob trigger (When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)) **>>** Get blob content using path (V2) **>>** Parse JSON **>>** SQL related Action (For instance I'm using **Insert row (V2)**).

Below is the sample JSON that I'm uploading to my container.

```
{
  "employees": {
    "emp_name": "abc",
    "hire_date": "2022-10-23",
    "salary": 10000
  }
}
```

I'm using triggers path to get the content of the blob. While Inserting the row I'm using Parse JSON values. Below is my Logic App.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**UPDATED ANSWER**

As per your requirement, you can either manually trigger flow using `` or set a recurrence trigger to make the flow triggered at times and then use list all files in that particular container from the storage account. Here is how the flow looks like

[image]

**detailed flow**

[image]

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

code view of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Get_blob_content_using_path_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/GetFileContentByPath",
                            "queries": {
                                "inferContentType": true,
                                "path": "@items('For_each')?['Path']",
                                "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Insert_row_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "emp_id": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['employees']?['employee_id']",
                                "emp_name": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['employees']?['emp_name']",
                                "hire_date": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['employees']?['hire_date']",
                                "salary": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['employees']?['salary']"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[employees]'))}/items"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Parse_JSON": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Parse_JSON": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "content": "@json(body('Get_blob_content_using_path_(V2)'))",
                            "schema": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "employees": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "emp_name": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "employee_id": {
                                                "type": "integer"
                                            },
                                            "hire_date": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "salary": {
                                                "type": "integer"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_blob_content_using_path_(V2)": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "ParseJson"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Lists_blobs_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Lists_blobs_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMQ=='))}",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": false
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMQ==": "/container1"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE GROUP NAME>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE GROUP NAME>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution.. One quick question.. what is the value of json expression in content box of parse json

Comment: @AnshMaheshwari, It is `json(body('Get_blob_content_using_path_(V2)'))`

Comment: Hi @SwethaKandikonda-MT, This worked for me. Thank you so much. One question, can we create event based trigger for blob storage in logic app without frequency basis? .

Comment: Also for above solution, is it advisable to use for each control to get blob content and parse the json and process further.

Comment: @AnshMaheshwari Sure you can do that

Comment: I am trying to parse 4 json files but they are getting triggered 4 times.. That means every file is getting processed 4 times instead of 1.

Comment: @AnshMaheshwari please try adding screenshots as we are unable to understand what schema you have implemented.

Comment: I unable to paste the screesnshot, I have added link in question for screenshot.

Comment: @AnshMaheshwari and what type of trigger you are using?

Comment: I am using as of now Blob storage trigger as when a blob is added or modified. Then listing the blob. After that above screenshot process begins.

Comment: As you are adding 4 files to the storage account, the flow gets triggered 4 times because you are using `When a blob is added or modified` trigger which triggers everytime a new blob gets added to the storage.

Comment: Could you please start the chat as I am unable to do so?

Comment: let's continue the discussion over here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244649/failed-to-start-logic-app-run-for-event-grid-trigger

Comment: I don't have that much reputation to chat. Would you please able to share the flow for when files are added to blob then list the files in azure logic app using when a resource event occurs. I am trying but flow itself is not getting triggered. TIA

Comment: @AnshMaheshwari Please check the updated answer

Comment: Could you please expand the workflow of first 2 steps?

Comment: @AnshMaheshwari Can you please check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks your flow is working for me. Only one problem I am facing is workflow is getting triggered for every file separately but it's getting processed in only one trigger. Rest all triggers are blank. How can I avoid the other triggers and keep just one for multiple files. I am using event grid blob trigger when blob is created.

Comment: Since the trigger you are using here is `event grid blob trigger when the blob is created` you will sure trigger the flow each time when a blob is added, its all in the trigger itself, If you want to trigger it only once then replace it with HTTP trigger or Recurrence Trigger so that it will trigger only once

Comment: Thanks for all your help. This issue is fixed and solution is working fine